# Preventing external elements from influencing flexbox image overflow in CSS?

Tags: html, css, highcharts, flexbox

When the screen is long enough, both charts fit fine. As the screen shortens vertically the charts adjust, but only to a point. After that point, the charts do not shrink anymore. In this example, right when the screen is too short that it just cuts the chart off, if you delete the div with the text inside it, the chart now fits into the screen. This occurs even though I have 'min-height of 0px'. **Question:** How can I make a flex container adjust its height/width when there are other elements on the page outside of the flex-container taking up space?

https://jsfiddle.net/we3wo9nv/

```
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div>This text is the main problem </div>
<div class="flex-container">

  <div id="chart-A" class="flex-item"></div>
  <div id="chart-B" class="flex-item"></div>
</div>


<div class="spacer"></div>




<style media="screen" type="text/css">



.spacer {
    height: 20px;
}
.flex-container {
    display:flex;
}
#chart-A{
    flex: 1

}
.flex-item {

    min-width:0px;
    min-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
#chart-B {
    flex:1




}


</style>










<script>
$(function() {
    // Create the first chart
    $('#chart-A').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column' // Chart type (i.e. 'bar', 'column', 'spline' etc)
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart A' // Title for the chart
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jane', 'John', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'jim']
            // Categories for the charts
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0, // Lowest value to show on the yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Burritos eaten' // Title for the yAxis
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false // Enable/Disable the legend
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true // If you have multiple series then all points in each category will show up on one tooltip
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Burritos', // Name of your series
            data: [5, 3, 8, 2, 4] // The data in your series

        }]
    });

    $('#chart-B').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart B'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jane', 'John', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'jim']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Taco bell visits'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Visits',
            data: [2, 4, 6, 5, 4]

        }]
    });
});


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks that charts work similar without custom text:
https://jsfiddle.net/we3wo9nv/2/ This issue may be caused by min-width in jsFiddle, because without any charts you cannot change width more than now: 
https://jsfiddle.net/we3wo9nv/4/